# How to track when a UIView is removed from superview without subclassing?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I want to make a class in my app that keeps track of when a registered UIView is removed from the screen. For instance, it would be like calling a `[MyViewTracker trackView:view]` and waiting for something like a delegate call or a notification of when it is removed.

Since I don't own the views, I can't subclass them to notify me, nor I was able to use KVO to track changes at `view.superview` or `view.window`. I could check from time to time if the views that are being tracked are still being showed, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Are there any other solutions that could be done? Maybe swizzling how a UIView works?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try to execute your logic using objective C blocks.

Comment: you can swizzle removeFromSuperview method and send a notification.

Comment: What was the problem using KVO?

Comment: `-[UIView superview]` is not KVO compliant, @shallowThought

Comment: Ah. Thanks @JoshCaswell

Comment: Marcel, what do you mean you can't subclass the views? Can't you use `@interface MyViewSubclass : MyViewTracker`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván When I say that I can't subclass a view, it is because the views I will tracking can be from third-parties (since this project will work as a library), so I have no control over them and want it to be as generic as possible. They are not custom views from my project (i.e., MyView : UIView).

Comment: I was able to do it by swizzling the `removeFromSuperview` method, although I still wonder if it is the proper/cleanest way to do it. I plan to put it in a library that others could use, so it is a bit scary to use swizzling. In the swizzling method, I am calling `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` before and after the original implementation, making it ~KVO Compliant~ and using as if KVO worked.

Comment: So you basically don't know which kind of object you'll be subclassing, as its class can vary. The first option that comes to my mind would be categories. But of course, you can't override methods with this, so swizzling is probably your only choice. A good and very common approach for this is to actually create a category and swizzling only the methods which are absolutely necessary. This is especially true when adding properties to a class with categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems hacky and something you should avoid, but you could swizzle `removeFromSuperview`, call your tracking method and call back the original implementation. That is if you really need to.
There is an excellent article about swizzling here: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html.

Comment: The OP said he can't subclass

Comment: I was able to do it by swizzling the `removeFromSuperview` method, although I still wonder if it is the proper/cleanest way to do it. I plan to put it in a library that others could use, so it is a bit scary to use swizzling. In the swizzling method, I am calling `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` before and after the original implementation, making it ~KVO Compliant~ and using as if KVO worked.